# Manual reference counting and AutoRelease

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease, reference-counting

In manual memory management on what scenarios you will go for Auto Release

I'd like to be well prepared as I am about to do a project using without ARC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically use `autorelease` when you need to return an object from a method, and relinquish ownership at the same time: upon returning the calling side (not the creating method) should own the object.

If you just relinquish ownership before returning the object (with `release`), it gets immediately deallocated and the calling side can not use it. If you don't call `release`, the object has a reference count of +1 from the called function (that instantiated it), which also has no further chance to release after the calling side has claimed ownership.

So, `autorelease` is like a "deferred release": the object gets sent one release method at a later time (but not before the function that is returning it returns).

---

#### Addendum:

The alternative approach is to return objects with an agreed-upon reference count of 1, and rely on the calling side to release it when done.

This is made explicit by adopting a preestablished naming pattern for those methods: In cocoa, they typically contain the words "alloc", "new", "copy" or "mutalbeCopy".

Source: [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).